# Apply Ito formula to $f(B_t,S_t)=(S_t-B_t)^2$ for $t\geq0$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

> Let  $S_t=\max_{0\leq s\leq t}B_s$ for $t\geq0$ and apply Ito formula to $f(B_t,S_t)=(S_t-B_t)^2$ for $t\geq0$. Determine the continuous local martingale  part and the bounded variation part in the resulting semi-martingale.

First, I apply Ito formula to $f(B_t,S_t)$:
$$
\begin{align}
df&=-2(S_t-B_t)dB_t+2(S_t-B_t)dS_t+(dB_t)^2+(dS_t)^2-2dB_tdS_t\\
&=-2(S_t-B_t)dB_t+2(S_t-B_t)dS_t+dt+(dS_t)^2-2dB_tdS_t
\end{align}
$$
I couldn't get how to simplify $(dS_t)^2$ and $dB_tdS_t$, because I haven't introduced max/sup/inf $B_t$ related process. It will be great help if anyone explain that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $S_t$ is an increasing process, it is of bounded variation. This implies that it has zero quadratic variation and its covariation with Brownian motion is zero. In terms of stochastic differentials, this means that$$(dS_t)^2 = dS_t dB_t = 0$$Thus Itô's formula gives you $$df = \underbrace{-2(S_t-B_t)dB_t}_{\text{local martingale}}+\underbrace{2(S_t-B_t)dS_t+dt}_{\text{bounded variation}}$$

Comment: How do you know that the second part is of bounded variation And that the first is  local martingale?

Comment: @Thomas The first part is an integral against Brownian motion, hence a local martingale.  The second part is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, so it can be decomposed into the difference of two increasing functions (thus making it a BV function) by separating the integrand into its positive and negative parts.

Comment: Thanks Jose I will try to do it

Comment: Thanks, @JoseAvilez, for your response. I understand why $X_t$ has zero quadratic variation but couldn't get the logic why the **covariation with Brownian motion is zero**? I was wondering what if the $X_t=\inf_{0\leq s\leq t}B_s$? Do I say it then decreasing process?

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory Try applying Cauchy-Schwartz to the covariation formula: loosely $|\langle X, B \rangle | \leq \langle X \rangle^{1/2}\langle B \rangle^{1/2} = 0$. 

Recall also that a function is of bounded variation iff it is the difference of two increasing functions. If $X_t$ is the running infimum, then it is a decreasing process, hence of bounded variation, so the arguments above carry through identically.

Comment: The question of why the covariation with brownian motion is zero should also be answered by the answer of @LucaMac, which shows that the covariation tends to zero almost surely in the continuous limit.

Comment: We have also to distinguish I guess between bounded variation and bounded quadratic variation. In your formula Jose shouldn't X and B be squared? Actually if they are not squared you have an issue because the brownian motion does not have bounded variation, but has bounded quadratic variation. But anyway I think they should be squared (?).

Comment: If they are squared, one can also observe to conclude from C.S. and the fact that a function with bounded variation (St) has zero quadratic variation

Comment: @Thomas by $\langle X \rangle$ and $\langle  B \rangle$ I mean their quadratic variations. In this context, C-S is more often known as the Kunita-Watanabe inequality.

Comment: Ah ok I am not so much into it. Thanks ! Strange notation by the way even if I see it is the used one...

Comment: What book would you suggest to investigate the relation between brownian motion, integration and martingale?

Comment: @Thomas For a gentle introductory treatment, Kuo's Introduction to Stochastic Integration is a good choice. A more advanced book you could also use is Diffusions, Markov Processes, and Martingales, by Rogers and Williams.

Comment: Maybe I would go for Kuo's than, thanks a lot !

Comment: By the way, I bought Kuo it should arrive the other week, looking forward to reading it :)

Comment: @Thomas Lovely! Glad you've decided to learn some stochastic analysis. I'm sure you'll enjoy the book. feel free to ask any questions you may have about it on MSE!

Answer (score 2):

Let $(X_t)_t$ be an increasing process.
This implies that $$ \sup_{t_1,\ldots,t_n} \sum_{i=1}^n |X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}| = X_T - X_0 < +\infty.$$
As a consequence, for any continuous $(Y_t)_t$, we have that $$ |\lim_{d(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}})(Y_{t_i}-Y_{t_{i-1}})| \leq\lim_{d(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}||Y_{t_i}-Y_{t_{i-1}}| \leq$$ $$\leq (X_T-X_0)\cdot\lim_{d(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\to0}\sup_i |Y_{t_i}-Y_{t_{i-1}}| = 0.$$

Can you calculate them from here?

Comment: I am afraid that I couldn't relate that with my question. As, I am learning stochastic calculus by my own in this pandemic situation, it will be great help for me if you add more details @LucaMac

Comment: $S$ is increasing, so use $X=S$. Moreover, both $S$ and $B$ are continuous. What's your your definition of quadratic (co)variation?